# How to do citations?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am looking for a way to do citations in Adobe InDesign, preferably without footnotes. I'm planning to write a document similar to a bachelors or masters theses. Therefore, it would be awesome to have an option to define a specific format e.g. [IEEE](https://ieee-dataport.org/sites/default/files/analysis/27/IEEE%20Citation%20Guidelines.pdf) for citations, so they are consistent throughout the document.

In case you know Tex, I am looking for such a functionality, but since I am planning to do a lot of designing I think that InDesign is better suited for the overall task of writing a academic document.

Comment: You'd be better off writing with a writing tool such as Word. There are different citation tools for it, and when you're done writing you can flatten everything into flat text (*highly* recommended as my experience with custom fields importing in InDesign is ... erratic) and only use InDesign for what it's designed: final layout of the document.

Comment: Ok i will research on how to export from word and import into InDesign. Makes sense that InDesign is better on the designing part of creating a document ;)

Comment: I wrote my BA and MA theses directly in InDesign. To me, the benefits outweighed the drawbacks, but citations are indeed a major drawback – I wrote and kept track of all my inline citations manually. Only the actual bibliography was created automatically using a reference manager, inserted into an empty Word document and then placed in InDesign. Someone was working on an InDesign plug-in for Zotero, but I don’t think it ever materialised.